# Anbox doesn't have a WiFi in settings

Tags: adb, wi-fi, anbox

I installed an Anbox to test a few features in a test app (the app needs a WiFi connection) but I found out that I don't have WiFi in the settings. Don't know what to do.

[image: There is no option to enable a WiFi]

[image]

I installed an Anbox without snap:
1)`apt install anbox`
2)`mkdir /var/lib/anbox`
3)`mv android_amd64.img /var/lib/anbox`

Image was downloaded from https://build.anbox.io/android-images/2018/07/19/

Comment: I would assume that this is because Anbox is not an emulator but just a run-time container for Android apps. It just provides network access without emulating a mobile or Wifi connection.

Comment: Based on [Docs » Advanced use » Network Configuration](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/advanced/network_configuration.html), I think Robert is right.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this, really I have an anbox0: 'ip' but why I don't have any internet connection? I'm trying to use a "WebView browser" in the anbox and always get this ERROR: Webpage not available  The webpage https://google.com/ could no be loaded because: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

When I use ifconfig inside of the container I don't see my wlan0 (only lo and eth0).